# How can I modify a Git repository to be more "branchy" as it should have been?

Tags: git

I have a Git repository, where there is only one branch "master".
So it is like

```
commit1 -> commit2 -> commit3 -> ... -> commit6
```

Some of the commits should have been created on a feature branch and then merged with "main". So I would like to modify the repository to be more "branchy" as it should have been.

I was wondering what commands I can use to move the last commit to a new feature branch, i.e.

```
commit1 -> commit2 -> commit3 -> ... -> commit5 (master branch) -> commit6 (featurebranch1)
```

?

Is it useful to move some commit(s) in the middle onto a new feature branch, and then merge it back to "master"?
For example,

```
commit1 (master branch) -> commit2 (featurebranch2) -> commit3 (master branch) -> ... -> commit5 (master branch) -> commit6 (featurebranch1)
```

?

Comment: Note that if you use something like "rebase + ff" as your merge strategy (which I personally perfer over merge commits, others may or may not agree) then the "branchiness" (which is basically just the existence of merge commits) won't be visible. In other words: you can easily pretend that you created feature branches and just merged them like that and it would look exactly like your repo currently does.

Comment: The goal of moving commits onto a branch and then merging them is just cosmetic, right? Are there some other changes that should really be happening on master (or a different  branch) in parallel?

Comment: @u there is only one repository

Comment: The first one, where you have six commits, and both master and feature point to the last commit, and you want to move master back one commit, is easily doable with e.g. git reset. And then you could merge it to master, but you'd have to use the --no-ff option, otherwise the fast forward merge will leave your commit tree exactly how it originally was. The second one can also be done by creating new branches (and maybe a master2 temp branch) and cherry-picking commits and then merging these branches to master2 with --no-ff. Then delete master2 and git branch --force master to last merge commit.

Comment: But only do this if you, for cosmetic reasons, want to make it look like there were branches, and you're the only one using the repo. If multiple people are using it, they'll get confused the next time they fetch. Another reason to do this would be if you want to learn more and/or become more familiar with how git works :D -- it would be a great exercise.

Comment: Just make sure you aren't confusing "merge" and "merge commit".  Commits themselves don't necessarily belong to one branch or another. A branch (informally) is really just all commits reachable from a given branch *head*. Commits may be reachable from multiple branch heads, and there isn't really anything that says which branch is the commit's "real" branch.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering what commands I can use to move the last commit to a new feature branch

For the last commits, assuming you are the only one working on that repository.:

```
git switch -c featurebranch1 master
git switch -C master @~
git push --force
```

For older commits, you would need to insert a merge commit, going from

```
c1--c2--c3--c4  (master)
To:
c1 -- M--c3--c4 (master)
  \  /
   c2
```

Which is

```
git switch -c tmp master
git switch -c featurebranch2 c2
git switch -C master c1
git merge --no-ff featurebranch2
git rebase --onto master c3~ tmp
git push --force
```